# OpenAM DesktopSSO support for non domain computers

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, saml-2.0, openam

I have configured OpenAM with the DesktopSSO module and everything is working fine with our SAML 2.0 app for domain computers. When they request the app, it redirects to OpenAM and they are immediately authenticated. I am trying to understand what config is needed in OpenAM to support non domain PC's. Is there an option in OpenAM to say 'if the device does not support this module, use another module' ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to default to another authentication module if the DesktopSSO module is unavailable.  You can do this by configuring another authentication module such as possibly an AD module and add the second module to the Authentication Chain.  Set the Criteria to SUFFICIENT for both modules in the chain and in the options include the following string iplanet-am-auth-shared-state-enabled=true for both modules.